# Disable the App global ThemeProvider for a specific component Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themeprovider

I'm working on a ReactJS project where some of the components are wrapped with  of Material-UI. But the App global theme overwrites the component style. Is there a way to disable the global style for a specific component?